# Can I share Items between characteers?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

As in most dungeon games a character in Dungeons of Dredmor finds many many items that are useless to them.  Full plate to the mage, staves to the rogue, etc, etc.  Is there a way in Dungeons of Dredmor to share or gift items between characters?

Comment: Remember that there's no penalty for using a weapon which you do not have a skill for (except dual wielding), so early on it's perfectly fine to use a weapon for which is not compatible with your character's skills.

Answer (score 5):

**Nope**; this game is supposed to be *hard* (-ish), so no giving your other characters a boost. Dungeons of Dredmor follows "Roguelike" themes, not "MMORPG" themes. Thus, you have (the option of) permadeath, and no sharing items between characters. If you take a crafting skill, you'll be able to get some items for your class; anything else you can't use is either merchant fodder, something you might be able to break down for parts, or fuel for the Horadric Lutefisk Cube.